# Creating a new Variable by passing multiple variables (number and a string)

Tags: python-3.x, string, variables, jupyter-notebook, parameter-passing

I am struggling with my first homework assignment involving working with the python 3 language. currently I am supposed to Create a variable my_intro by passing your variables my_name and my_age into your make_introduction() function. Print the variable after you create it. I am currently getting the error message: 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 my_intro = make_introduction(my_name, my_age)
      2 print(my_intro)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I am doing my homework on a Jupyter Notebook and believe my possible problem may lie in the previous line of code I have to run in the assignment.

I have tried several different coding options including using the str argument before my_age

the line coded for my age

```
# create a variable stating my age
my_age = 24
print(my_age)
```

The line just before my problem

```
make_introduction = "Hello, my name is, " + my_name + " and I'm " + str(my_age) + " years old."
print(make_introduction)
```

The line that shows the error

```
my_intro = make_introduction(my_name, my_age)
print(my_intro)
```

I expect the output to be something like Hello, my name is, Kaitlyn Griffith and I'm 24 years old.

however what I am seeing is: str object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

The following line creates a variable:

```
make_introduction = "Hello, my name is, " + my_name + " and I'm " + str(my_age) + " years old."
```

What you need is a function. And it should look like:

```
def make_introduction(my_name, my_age):
    return "Hello, my name is, " + my_name + " and I'm " + str(my_age) + " years old."
```

Functions are callable (e.g. `make_introduction('Diego', 32)`). By callable, it means you can append `()` after the object name.

So, your full example could look like:

```
my_age, my_name = 24, 'Mike'

# Function declaration begins in the following line
def make_introduction(my_name, my_age):
    return "Hello, my name is, " + my_name + " and I'm " + str(my_age) + " years old."
# Function declaration ended in previous line (Note: the `:` and indentation)

my_intro = make_introduction(my_name, my_age)  # This line captures the function output into my_intro
print(my_intro)
```